# Best way to select rows and respective columns below a certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with 30+ columns.

The first two columns ("A" and "B") contain general infromation about a feature, while the rest of columns represent different experiments for that feature.

I want to slice my dataframe to only contain rows with respective columns, in which any value was below a threshold, and furthermore include columns A and B.

My current code looks like this :

```
df=df.loc[df.le(0.05).any(1),].reindex(colums=["A","B"]+list(df.columns[df.le(0.05).any(0)]))
```

While it works, this looks very inelegant. Is there a "nicer" way to go about?

edit:
Example

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0.9 | 0.8 | 0.04 |
| 1 | 20 | 0.7 | 0.6 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.1 | 0.01 | 0.3 |

and as result

| A | B | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0.8 | 0.04 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.01 | 0.3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df=df.loc[df.le(0.05).any(1),['A','B',*df.columns[df.le(0.05).any(0)]]]
#OR
df=df.loc[df.le(0.05).any(1),(df.le(0.05).any(0)) | (df.columns.isin(['A','B']))]
```

output of `df`:

```
    A   B   D       E
0   1   10  0.80    0.04
2   2   5   0.01    0.30
```

Comment: @GeorgB kindly check the answer **:)**

Comment: That was my original approach, but givin list-likes to loc is no longer supported.

Comment: @GeorgB what is your pandas version? and both codes giving you this warning?

Comment: 1.1.3    The second option omits column A and B

Comment: @GeorgB I am using `1.2.4` and both are working fine

Comment: Updated pandas to 1.31, and both versions worked :)

Comment: @GeorgB ohh nice btw that was a warning not an error so you can ignore that ***;)***

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this input:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'A': ['feature']*5,
                              'B': ['feature']*5,}),
                pd.DataFrame({'col%s' % i: np.random.randint(0,5,5) for i in range(10)})
               ], axis=1)
```

input:

```
         A        B  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  feature  feature     3     0     1     3     4
1  feature  feature     4     0     2     4     1
2  feature  feature     0     1     4     2     1
3  feature  feature     1     4     2     4     0
4  feature  feature     3     4     4     2     1
```

Now we select the rows where there is not at least one 0 (just an example, you can use any selector here):

```
df[df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1).le(0).any(axis=1)]
```

output:

```
         A        B  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  feature  feature     3     0     1     3     4
1  feature  feature     4     0     2     4     1
2  feature  feature     0     1     4     2     1
3  feature  feature     1     4     2     4     0
```

Comment: My goal is to also drop col2 and and col3 in your example. I want the rows where any value was under the threshold, and only relevant columns (so columns which never have 0 in your example should be removed)